# Debugging deployed AIR application

Tags: debugging, air

Is it possible to attach a debugger to an AIR process like it is in Java? What's the best option for me to debug an AIR application that must be done in production (will not work in FlexBuilder due tom some integration issues).

Comment: What problem are you facing with FB3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a new debugger called [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/). A bunch of blog posts mention it as promising so it might be worth checking out.

Too add to that: for logging, you can use the Flex framework logging API to create a custom ILoggingTarget implementation that writes to an XML socket or to a file for instance.